# redirect to root login page from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am redirect user to loging page when session expires. `Login.aspx` is in root.

I declared path like this in web.config file.

```
     <forms name=".FormsAuth" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"  protection="All" 
slidingExpiration="false" requireSSL="false" >
```

It is working for all root `.aspx` pages. But it not working for sub folders pages like `Reporting\report.aspx`.

So how to manage redirect page (Login.aspx) for root .aspx pages and sub folder .aspx pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your config. It seems to me that your tag Forms is not closed properly.
If you have these 2 sections it must work:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".FormsAuth" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" slidingExpiration="false" requireSSL="false" />
 </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

You can find a sample app [here](http://cid-669adf1af64df389.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/WebApplication1.zip).

Comment: @James123: Have you tried my sample? It must work even with subfolders, unless you override it, using a different web.config file in the subfolder. Can you put some code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the directories named secure and admin are the only directories that are protected
you need manually secure the directorie you want using the below:

```
<location path="secure">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: can you please post your web.config file

Comment: Wait, did you just say that there is an invisible security rule for the folders named Secure and Admin?

Comment: I agree with Chris. That's not true.

Comment: Secure and Admin are prodected by default

http://myhosting.com/kb/ASP.NET_Forms_Authentication

Comment: for myhosting.com customers, maybe?

Comment: that one was just an example anyway you have to specify what falder are protected and what users can access them. If you post your web.config I can have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

All sub-folders must have their own web.config files that deny access to anonymous users such as:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />                      <!--Deny all Anonymous (not logged in) users-->
        <allow roles="admin,manager,cservice"/> <!--Permit users in these roles-->
        <deny users="*"/>                       <!--Deny all users-->
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the

System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();

Which redirects to login page set in the config if you are suffering to redirect directly with response.redirect or server.transer

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx

Here is the basics to set up Forms Authentication:

web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Logon page:

```
<script runat="server">
  void Logon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if ((UserEmail.Text == "jchen@contoso.com") && 
            (UserPass.Text == "37Yj*99Ps"))
      {
          FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage 
             (UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked);
      }
      else
      {
          Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
      }
  }
</script>
```

Signout page:

```
<script runat="server">
  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Welcome.Text = "Hello, " + Context.User.Identity.Name;
  }

  void Signout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("Logon.aspx");
  }
</script>
```