# how to redirect user to login page after restricting them in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I restrict my users for accessing some pages
Web.config code

```
 <location path="Pages/Management.aspx">
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="admin" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="Pages/ShoppingCart.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

but  when I tried to access that page in place of redirecting me to login page it redirects me to this page 
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

My Question Is
**how to redirect users towards login page?**

thank you

Comment: Form authentication? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227779/redirect-to-root-login-page-from-web-config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect to root login page from web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227779/redirect-to-root-login-page-from-web-config)

Answer (score 0):

see the link that Enkode put above for some good info. you could also do something like:

```
if(!User.IsInRole("str"))
    Response.Redirect("str");
```